# How do I find the column headers of various types of csv files in a folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have an issue where I need to intake different files, with different column locations.  One files column might start 4 rows down, whereas another files columns might start on row one.

One file might look like this:

```
This
is
a
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4
```

Another might have columns like this on row 1:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3
```

I need to get a list of every files column headers.  I consider a column header a list greater than 3 items.  If I'm using the csv module how can I write this?

I have something like:

```
temprow = next(csvfile)

for value in temprow:
    if value == '':
        temprow = next(csvfile)
    if len(value) > 3:
        header = temprow
    else:
        header = temprow
```

This is not quite working as it is also returning columns that contain 1 string.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` statements execute the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:                        # iterate for each line
        if "," in line:                   # the header line should contain comma     
            header = line          
            break                         # break the loop when header line is found

print(header)
```

Output:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the specifications in your post, this code works. It returns the first row in a .csv file that has 4 or more elements ('greater than 3 items').

```
headers = []                                        # Column names will be appended to this list
files = ['./test']                                  # Insert files here

for f in files:                                     # Loop over files
    with open(f, 'r') as fh:                        # Open file
        reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter = ',')    # Create reader
        for row in reader:                          # Loop over rows
            if len(row) >= 4:                       # Criteria for appending to headers
                headers.append(row)
```

Comment: You're not opening the csv files properly for either Python 2 or 3. Check out the examples in the documentation.

Comment: You probably also need a `break` after the `headers.append(row)` statement. In addition, since this isn't in a function, the `return headers` at the end is an error.

Comment: @Martineau The `break` isn't needed as long as only one line fulfills the criteria for being a headers line, but could be added. The code will achieve the same result under basic assumptions about the types of file OP is working with. In terms of the `csv` module, I fail to see how this is incorrect. See the first example under [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents). The only immediate thing I notice is the `quotechar` optional argument. I've edited the `return` part to print instead, but trust OP knows how to handle this part.

Comment: It's extremely likely that _all_ the lines following the header row will meet the criteria—think about it. As for opening the file, the Python 2 documentation you linked to show the file being opened for reading in binary mode, `'rb'`, which is not what's in your answer. In Python 3, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) show the file being opened for reading with the `newline=''` keyword argument which is need because in that version of Python strings are Unicode by default...continued

Comment: ...For generality, hardcoding a length of 4 is also likely not going to work unless all the files have at least that many columns.

Comment: Using `with open(f, 'r') as fh:` works just fine, which you can easily verify yourself; whether the example was for a binary file or not is irrelevant, it creates an opened file which is then passed to the csv reader. This is the way I always iterate over `.csv` files.

Comment: In terms of hard coding the number 4, I would suggest reading the original post again: 'I consider a column header a list greater than 3 items.' Obviously this can be generalized by making the code part of a function that takes an argument with the expected number of column headers, but why? The solution that I've provided answers the original question as it was specifically asked. We're not arguing best programming practices here, but trying to answer a specific question.

Comment: Just because the OP said they considered a row a column header if it had more than 3 items doesn't mean it a good idea. As for opening the file, I'm fairly sure you don't understand how the `csv` module operates, because to work correctly it needs text files opened in binary mode so it can handle newlines embedded in fields properly. It's quite possible you didn't run into this issue in your testing because none of the your test files had that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about `csv` now, it looks like the `'rb'` distinction is necessary for Windows, but not for Unix-based OS. I'm using Linux, which is why this works for me.

Comment: Perhaps that's it. The linked documentation just says to use `'rb'` probably because that will make work on both OSs (even if unnecessary on Linux). Plus the OP as given no indication of what OS they're using, so better to play it safe IMO.

Comment: Agreed, good to know since I use both OSs. Thanks for pointing it out.